# How do I make an animation image responsive?

Tags: css, image, animation, responsive

I make the image move up and down within a certain range
But when I reduce the screen the image shifts from its place, I want it to be stable How is that?

```css
.image_it{
  width: 85px;
  position:fixed;
  top: 450px;
  left: 320px;
  animation: animate1 7s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate1 {
  0%,100% {
      transform: translateY(11px);
  }
  50% {
      transform: translateY(-11px);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <img src="/images/it.jpg" alt="IT" class="image_it">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of using fixed px dimensions try using relative ones (%) to see if that helps.

Comment: Did  the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.image_it {
  width: 50%;
  animation: animate1 7s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate1 {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: translateY(11px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-11px);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1633917737415-3549f9a77cd5?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw5fHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="IT" class="image_it">
</body>

</html>
```